# How to implement a overlay button which is floating over the content view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, overlay, floating

in some iPhone apps i saw a **button** which was **floating over the content view**, eg. in the app EyeEm. When the user is scrolling the content, the button remains where it is and is still an interaction element.[image: Overlay Button which is floating over the content view]

Ho do I implement this?

My approach would be:

- Create a view with content
- Put a button on it
- **But how to make the button floating?**

edit:

The floating seems to be the default behavior. Interestingly `addSubview` and `insertSubview` have the same behavior when placing the button... both are floating over the content.

```
- (void)addOverlayButton {
UIButton *oButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[oButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[oButton setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
oButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:oButton];
//[self.view insertSubview:oButton aboveSubview:_scrollView];  // same result as addSubview. 
// Both solutions let the button float over the content. 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a subview to your window's content view with `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` method with your button and scrollview as arguments, but be careful: if two sibling views both have transparency, the resulting drawing behaviour is undefined.

Comment: addSubview seems to have the floating behaviour as default.. see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

if you using storyboard just add button over it, like [image: that]

if you want to do with code `insertSubview:buttonView aboveSubview:scrollView`

no matters its table or scroll view

Comment: does work, if in the content area everything is created by the storyboard. But I have content which is created programmatically and in this circumstance the button is not shown. I assume he is hidden under the programmed-content. Perhaps I have to lift the button up somehow, so that the layer is over the programmed-content.