# floating UIButton with image on a UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, overlay, floating

I try to implement a floating button over a `UITableview`. So that when the content scrolls the button stay at the same position. The button shall hold a transparent image.

I did a [smoketest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040776/how-to-implement-a-overlay-button-which-is-floating-over-the-content-view) and it worked fine with `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`respectivly `addSubView`

But doing this on a `UITableview` of an `TableViewController` does not seem to work. The Button is on the tableView and scrolls with the tableView. Interestingly it scrolls as well under the header of the tableView...

How do I fix this - that the button is floating over the tableview?

#### TableViewController.m (updated with working code 12.07.2013)

**Edit**: Added a `@property (nonatomic) float originalOrigin;` in TableViewController.h

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];       
    self.originalOrigin = 424.0;
    [self addOverlayButton];
}


#pragma mark Camera Button 
- (void)addOverlayButton {
    // UIButton *oButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.oButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.oButton.frame = CGRectMake(132.0, self.originalOrigin, 56.0, 56.0);
    self.oButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.oButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CameraButton56x56.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.oButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toCameraView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.oButton aboveSubview:self.view];
}

// to make the button float over the tableView including tableHeader
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGRect floatingButtonFrame = self.oButton.frame;
    floatingButtonFrame.origin.y = self.originalOrigin + tableBounds.origin.y;
    self.oButton.frame = floatingButtonFrame;

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.oButton]; // float over the tableHeader
}
```

Comment: Best answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35622509/2269679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate to change your floating button y origin while the user scroll the table, so that the button will float and stay at the same location.

There is a great example in **WWDC 2011 session 125** that does exactly what you want.

In general, you need to save the original y origin of the button after you create it, or you can do it in `viewDidLoad`, then implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` and update the button frame.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect tableBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    CGRect floatingButtonFrame = self.floatingButton.frame;
    floatingButtonFrame.origin.y = self.originalOrigin + tableBounds.origin.y;
    self.floatingButton.frame = floatingButtonFrame;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works partly. The button stays now where it should. But I have the strange behaviour, that the button is over the tablecells, but under the tableheader. So verytime the tableheader appears the button scrolls under the table header..

Comment: Found a solution, adding: `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.oButton];` to the `scrollViewDidScroll` did the trick

Comment: updated my code with the working solution

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == _tableContacts)
    {
        CGRect frame = _btnAddNewContact.frame;
        frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + _tableContacts.frame.size.height - _btnAddNewContact.frame.size.height;
        _btnAddNewContact.frame = frame;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_btnAddNewContact];
    }
}