# It is possible to create a floating button in tableview bottom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, floating-action-button

In my application i have a UIViewController in that one tableview with two custom cells,i want to display a floating button in my tableview.it is possible,it is possible give me some suggestion r link.
Thank you in advance!
"That question is not related to my question.i have a two custom cells with different heights in one tableview."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [floating UIButton with image on a UITableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593687/floating-uibutton-with-image-on-a-uitableview)

Comment: @ShehzadAli i have two custom cells with different heights,it is possible.

Comment: Have you achieved floating button functionality with one custom cell in UITableView?

Comment: ok. i will try and inform you@ShehzadAli

Comment: Another link for your help [floating Button] (https://github.com/gizmoboy7/VCFloatingActionButton)

Comment: let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keywindow; window.addSubview(YourButtonView);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

Here is the simple solution for adding a floating button to our application.
we can add a button through "storyboard" like this

[image]

after adding the button create action what do you want.it's working fine.
thank you.